# Как поступать с вопросами, где просят ссылки на что-то? Стоит ли просто оставлять ссылку в комментариях?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202965/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-singleliveevent) такого вопроса. Цитата:

> Есть рабочий пример SingleLiveEvent? Ссылочку, если можно

Тут просят ссылку на пример кода, но ответы-ссылки не поощряются сообществом, насколько я знаю. И тревогу ставить на него вроде бы не за что и как давать ответ не понятно. Как бы вы поступили с таким вопросом?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Все как обычно - разместить в ответе основной ответ (*рабочий пример SingleLiveEvent*), и добавить ссылку на источник и дополнительные подробности, если они есть.

ИМХО, просьбу о ссылке, в таком случае, из вопроса можно и убрать, т.к. она там явно фигура речи - *"помогите мне как-нибудь как вам проще, хотя бы ссылкой"*, а не буквальное *"мне нужна именно ссылка и ничего больше"*.

Comment: недавно, кстати, я наблюдал вопрос, в котором человек просил исполняемый файл малоизвестного инструмента, так как не мог нигде найти (его и правда нигде нет). вопрос хоть и удалили (кстати, непонятно почему), но можете ли вы прокомментировать, как отвечать на такие вопросы? вроде как и основной ответ давать не из чего, да и проблема в том, что человек не мог найти файл, а я имею ссылку на старый архивный репозиторий с этим файлом, не расписывать же мне, откуда я взял ссылку

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov вопросы такого плана плохо подходят для SO. 1. Ответ будет ссылкой, то есть рискует достаточно быстро "протухнуть" и не сохраниться даже в wayback machine. 2. Исполняемые файлы - это черные коробки, непонятно что у них внутри (в т.ч. и зловред). Ссылка на исходники была бы куда лучше. 3. SO ориентирован на решение проблем, когда сначала формулируется задача, а потом к ней предлагается решение. Нет оснований полагать, что только некий определеннй инструмент может решить задачу ТС.

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, очевидно надо помочь человеку, тем самым выполнить главное предназначение данного ресурса -- конкретная помощь друг другу